# Executing Post request in Laravel gives TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have a `Note` model with title and content attributes. I also have views that display all notes (index) and specific note (show). That works fine.
Now I was about to create a form and create Notes from the form, and there was an [error](https://gist.github.com/dragify/4265b97c74fe30b1ed39af9f54228442): `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`.
Here is my Routes file:

```
Route::get('/notes', 'NotesController@index');
Route::get('notes/{note}', 'NotesController@show');

Route::post('/notes', 'NotesController@create');
```

My [controller](https://gist.github.com/dragify/a45871b734d60c03e16b01a554b8f446) is on Gist.

And my [view](https://gist.github.com/dragify/8916887a6f121c22cd1fd52915221610).

How can I get rid of this error, and what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"/>
```

and have a look at [laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: It didn't work. I get the same result.
You mean, like this, or?
<form  method="post" action="/notes">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="text" name="content">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>

Comment: I'd place it in front of the submit button, but yes.

Comment: Now it works :)
I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes. 
Where can I learn why is this necessary?

Comment: It's for your (and your users) security only. It prevents cross origin requests to your urls . Just click the link I've posted above and follow the docs, they hold the information you're after @DragosStrugar

Comment: You're welcome! @DragosStrugar ... really... read the docs in a silent minute. Laravel has made them really good and easy to read

Comment: I will surely do now. I'm following laracasts for now, and he is making things clear, but he hasn't mentioned these tokens. I'll check it out right away.

Comment: The lesson about tokens is a really old one. I think it's like 2 years from now that I saw it. But following laracasts surely is a good idea. --- But again, I hate reading documentation, but laravel's is quite good to read. :-) @DragosStrugar

Answer (score -2):

Change your view to

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'notes','method'=>'POST')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('content', 'Title') !!}
    {!! Form::text('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: This is Laravel's Form facade. refer further : http://laravel-recipes.com/categories/21